# How do i navigate to other Screen in Overlay widget? onTap function not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

Selected menu item fails to navigate to the screen/page assigned
Have tried using the Drawer and appBar without the overlay widget but gave error **"No Overlay Widget"**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const WelcomeScreen(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Overlay(initialEntries: [ //<--- Overlay widget preventing Navigation**
          OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 65.0,
                      child: DrawerHeader(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green.shade900,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'Menu',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                      title: const Text('Profile'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const Profile(
                              profileId: '',
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(
                  'welcome',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade900,
              ),
             
            );
          }),
        ]);
      },
    );
  }
```

Selected menu item fails to navigate to the screen/page assigned
Have tried using the Drawer and appBar without the overlay widget but gave error **"No Overlay Widget"**

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do want to navigate to another page from a drawer? It would be helpful if you explained want you expect to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, i want to navigate to other screen/page once the menu items is click. onTap has been set to the various items